# CMake acusa múltiplas declarações de uma classe

Tags: c++, cmake

Estrutura do "projeto":

> ->loja
>   ---->[loja.cpp](https://pastebin.com/QRyY6FL8)
>   ---->[loja.h](https://pastebin.com/vdYF7YLx)
>   ---->[main.cpp](https://pastebin.com/kXGVpKH3)
>   ---->[CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/ApPvQyka)

Quando eu tento compilar o VSCode acusa que existem multiplas denifições do membros da classe. Sendo que se eu colocar um inline no arquivo de cabeçalho ele compila.

> [build] Starting build
>   [proc] Executing command: C:\Tools\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --build "c:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/build" --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
>   [build] Scanning dependencies of target app
>   [build] [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/loja.cpp.obj
>   [build] [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.obj
>   [build] [100%] Linking CXX executable app.exe
>   [build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a(loja.cpp.obj): in function `ZN4loja5helloERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE':
>   [build] C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/loja.cpp:13: multiple definition of`loja::hello(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'; CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/loja.cpp:13: first defined here
>   [build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a(loja.cpp.obj): in function `ZlsRSoRK4loja':
>   [build] C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/loja.cpp:17: multiple definition of`operator<<(std::ostream&, loja const&)'; CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/loja.cpp:17: first defined here
>   [build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a(loja.cpp.obj): in function `ZrsRSiR4loja':
>   [build] C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/loja.cpp:22: multiple definition of`operator>>(std::istream&, loja&)'; CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Henrique/Documents/My Projects/Loja/loja.cpp:22: first defined here
>   [build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   [build] CMakeFiles\app.dir\build.make:99: recipe for target 'app.exe' failed
>   [build] mingw32-make.exe[2](https://pastebin.com/vdYF7YLx): *** [app.exe] Error 1
>   [build] CMakeFiles\Makefile2:967: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/app.dir/all' failed
>   [build] mingw32-make.exe[1](https://pastebin.com/QRyY6FL8): *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
>   [build] Makefile:115: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   [build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
>   [build] Build finished with exit code 2

Porque isso acontece? E como resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias coisas erradas nesse projeto.

Aqui vai uma solução que funciona.
Pode ser (bem) melhorada, mas pelo menos compila e executa sem erros.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(LojaHeranca VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(app main.cpp loja.cpp)
```

loja.h

```
#ifndef LOJA_H
#define LOJA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// desaconselhavel colocar isso dentro de um include!!!
using namespace std;

class loja {

  private:
    string nome;

public:
    loja(string n = "Sem Nome") : nome(n) { cout << "Construindo..." << endl; }
    ~loja() { cout << "Destruindo..." << endl; };
    void hello(std::string const &name);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const loja &l);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, loja &l);
};
#endif // LOJA_H
```

loja.cpp

```
#include "loja.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
/*
loja::loja(string n = "Sem Nome") {
    cout << "Construindo..." << endl;
}

loja::~loja() {
    cout << "Destruindo..." << endl;
}
*/
void loja::hello(std::string const &name) {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const loja &l) {
  out << l.nome << endl;
  return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, loja &l) {
  cout << "Enter the name: ";
  in >> l.nome;
  return in;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "loja.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  loja f;
  f.hello("Teste");
}
```

Comment: Eu preciso de uma forma sistemática de adicionar libs e linkalas ao programa principal. Sendo que existe a linkagem entre bibliotecas também.

Comment: abra uma outra pergunta com um projeto que tenha libs...este projeto que você mostrou aqui não tem libs...e tem uma coisa muito estranha: include de .cpp...é muito raro isso ser necessário, e neste caso aqui causava os erros de multipla definição

Comment: A dúvida é: como linhar corretamente a lib loja.h com o programa principal.

Comment: sua terminologia está errada: "loja.h" não é uma lib, é um include...lib seria um arquivo .lib ou .dll no Windows, e .so no Linux; o cmake tem vários comandos relacionados a includes, mas nesse seu pequeno projeto não foi necessário usar esses comandos

Comment: Agora tudo faz sentido. Então, preciso aprender como linhar includes ao meu programa principal. É isso?

Comment: não entendi o que você disse, não sei o que é "linhar"

Comment: Eu quis dizer: linkar. Desculpe.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução nesse [link](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-September/024226.html) nele é dito que para evitar o problema é só adicionar uma configurações no arquivo do CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_source_files_properties(${SRCS} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
```

No caso SRCS são todos meus arquivos de implementação dos membros das classes.